# Dynamic tabs in scrollable tab view react native

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I need to use scrollable Tab View https://github.com/skv-headless/react-native-scrollable-tab-view with dynamic contents .

For Eg, the tabs can vary according to the array.

Is this possible to load dynamic tabs with scrollable tab view in react native.

Comment: are you facing any problems in implementing it?

Answer (score 0):

Do it the react way:

```
<ScrollableTabView>
    {tabs.map(tab => <ScrollView key={tab.id} tabLabel={tab.label}>{tab.component}</ScrollView>)}
</ScrollableTabView>
```

Comment: Hi @Khushboo, did Saravanabalagi's solution worked. coz i too have the same requirement.